# How do i make my webpage scroll to a particular section of my web page by clicking a link on my navigation bar

Tags: html

`

Home

Home

Home

`
`

## it did not scroll to this page

`

I was expecting it to scroll to that particular section. some scrolled while some did not please what should I do to make them work perfectly again. please I need assistance

Comment: Use an id in a section like this: `<section id="myid"></section>` And then in the link anchor tag `href` attribute set the id like this: `<a href="#myid"></a>` And it will work.

Comment: Additionally, you can use `html{scroll-behavior: smooth;}` to make the scrolling smooth.

Answer (score 0):

Do the code as mentioned below:

```html
 
  <!-- navbar links -->
  <li>
   <a href="#content">Scroll Down</a>
 </li>
 <!--Put the following content on the bottom of html document.-->
 <a name="content">The content here where you want to go</a>
```